# Calculating a transformation matrix from 3 transformed vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Good afternoon,

I am trying top calculate a transformation matrix from 3 transformed points, essentially a triangle. I need to determine camera pose w.r.t world using those 3 points
The lengths of the sides of the triangle do not change in either coordinate system, so this is purely a euclidean transformation.

I understand that 3 points  = 9 equations
A rotation matrix has 6 unique values + 3 translated, so I assume there is only 1 4x4 transformation matrix for this solution.

The way I thought to proceed with this is to

1. Find normalized vectors to each point in triangle ABC, these would be oA, oB, oC, and OA, OB, and OC
2. Pick one vector as the X axis, Pick triangle OAB as the XY plane, then using cross product, find two orthogonal vectors: OZ and OY. Repeat for oz and oy in the other coordinate system
3. Construct rotation matrix using α = acos(OZ.oz) , β =acos(OY.oy) , γ=acos(OA.oa)

(from wikipedia:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)

[image]

4. Find the inverse of the matrix, multiply each vector in coordinate system 2 by it, and add it to the respective vector in coordinate system 1. All 3 resulting vectors should be exactly the same, and give me the transformation vector

Does this sound right?

I know this problem is solved, is there a more elegant or complete solution for it?
Am I correct to assume there is only 1 solution for this?

### Thanks